# How to freeze location of a child gameObject relative to the father?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8pHo.png)

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvnVK.png)

Hello everyone, i have issue in my Untity project.I want that health bar to not spin after his parent object, you can see it in 1 screenshot. But in reality, because it`s childer object, it rotates after his parent, so it is possible to freeze that spin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to control healthbar rotation every frame. Write a script which will make your health bar always look to the camera. Use

```
transform.LookAt(cameraPosition);
```

or

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToCamera);
```

Also, you can separate your health bar from a character and write simple follow script with delta parameter exposed in inspector

Comment: Or even simpler: Add a parent that does not rotate and make the healthbar and the rotating sprite a child. No need for fancy code, just smart organization. Movement is handled by the parent, rotation by the child.

Comment: You’re right. But a new problem can appear. If the character will move along X axis relative to the camera, the bar will look strange, because it’s not looking to us, having the same rotation. I guess it will look scaled along X))0)

Comment: As this looks like a 2D sprite, I suppose the rotation axis is only ever perpendicular to the screen, so shortening due to rotation won't happen. But in 3D you're right, your solution would be required.